# Is there a way not to switch to darkmode while system is in darkmode in jetpack?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-darkmode

I want the same display as in the lightmode when darkmode is on. Is there an easier way without hardcoding every textfields,buttons etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new Jetpack compose project in Android studio, you are likely to get a `Theme.kt` file with a `LightColorPalette`, `DarkColorPalette` and a theme composable. The theme composable usually looks like;

```
@Composable
fun SampleAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        content = content
    )
}
```

You can just replace `isSystemDarkTheme()` with `false` to lock your app into just light theme mode.